# require help in routing in asp.net core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-core-3.0

In my regular MVC project i handle routing like below and there are similar routings for other pages as well.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "", 
        url: "login", 
        defaults: new { controller = "Access", action = "SignIn", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

but am not able to do it in asp.net core 3.0.

When i tried to use the similar approach in asp.net core 3.0, the page is redirecting. but the styles and scripts are not getting loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added the following settings at the Configure Method of Startup.cs

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
});
```

Also, set your route inside of UseEndpoints method as follows:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Access}/{action=SignIn}/{id?}");
    });
```